# Is there a way to get following output in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table(product_tb):

```
  id   product   unit   quantity
 ---- --------- ------ ----------
   1   A         1kg         100
   2   B         1kg          50
   3   A         5kg          50
```

I want output as:

```
  product   1kg   2kg   5kg
 --------- ----- ----- -----
  A         100     0    50
  B          50     0     0
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, there is a way in most (all?) databases. Unfortunately, we don't know which one you are using :-)

Comment: Also, can you double check the desired output? I can't see what the idea is

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt. And don't forget to specify dbms.

Comment: I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes with [CASE WHEN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql) and aggregations. Try this:

```
SELECT product, SUM(CASE WHEN unit='1kg' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS '1kg', 
                SUM(CASE WHEN unit='2kg' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS '2kg',
                SUM(CASE WHEN unit='5kg' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS '5kg'
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY product, unit;
```

To add the total do:

```
SELECT product, SUM(CASE WHEN unit='1kg' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS '1kg', 
                SUM(CASE WHEN unit='2kg' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS '2kg',
                SUM(CASE WHEN unit='5kg' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS '5kg',
                SUM(quantity) AS Total
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY product, unit;
```

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions...

Comment: Should be `GROUP BY product` then it will generate the correct results.. And manual PIVOTing is better done by using the MAX function instead.

Comment: how can i add a column that display the total quantity in the output table

Comment: I just added that!

Answer (score 0):

Most DBMS Support `PIVOT` operator

```
select * from
( 
   select Product, Unit, quantity from table
) t
pivot
(
    max(quantity) for Unit in([1kg], [2kg] ,[5kg])
)a
```